# Cannot find control with name: 'ingredients angular error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, types

### my HTML component file

I have searched the  net all day but can't get to fix this issue, below is my HTML file
I'm trying to get the input form at the end work but keep getting the error (shown below)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form [formGroup]="BugForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              formControlName="name"
              class="form-control"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imagePath">Image URL</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="imagePath"
              formControlName="imagePath"
              class="form-control"
              #imagePath
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <img [src]="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea
              type="text"
              id="description"
              class="form-control"
              formControlName="description"
              rows="6"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Please select Bug Priority:</p>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="low"
              name="priority"
              value="low"
              formControlName="priority"
            />
            <label for="male">Low</label><br />
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="medium"
              name="priority"
              value="medium"
              formControlName="priority"
            />
            <label for="female">Medium</label><br />
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="high"
              name="priority"
              value="high"
              formControlName="priority"
            />
            <label for="other">High</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Please select Bug Status:</p>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="open"
              name="status"
              value="open"
              formControlName="status"
            />
            <label for="male">Open</label><br />
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="ongoing"
              name="status"
              value="ongoing"
              formControlName="status"
            />
            <label for="female">OnGoing</label><br />
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="closed"
              name="status"
              value="closed"
              formControlName="status"
            />
            <label for="closed">closed</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ingredients might wana remove -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" formArrayName="ingredients">
          <div
            class="row"
            style="margin-top: 10px"
            *ngFor="let ingredientCtrl of getControls(); let i = index"
            [formGroupName]="i"
          >
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <input type="text" 
              class="form-control" 
              formControlName="name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <input
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="amount"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Bug</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

### my Ts file

this below is my ts component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute,Params} from '@angular/router';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-recipe-edit",
  templateUrl: "./recipe-edit.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./recipe-edit.component.css"],
})
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  editMode = false;
  BugForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private recipeService: RecipeService
  ) {}
  // get controls() {
  //   // a getter!
  //   return (<FormArray>this.BugForm.get("ingredients")).controls;
  // }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params["id"];
      this.editMode = params["id"] != null;
      this.initForm();
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.BugForm);
  }
  getControls() {
    return (this.BugForm.get("ingredients") as FormArray).controls;
  }

  private initForm() {
    let bugName = "";
    let bugImagePath = "";
    let bugDescription = "";
    let bugPriority = "";
    let bugStatus = "";
    let BugIngredients = new FormArray([]);

    if (this.editMode) {
      const bug = this.recipeService.getRecipe(this.id);
      bugName = bug.name;
      bugImagePath = bug.imagePath;
      bugDescription = bug.description;
      bugPriority = bug.priority;
      bugStatus = bug.status;
      if (bug["ingredients"]) {
        for (let ingredient of bug.ingredients) {
          BugIngredients.push(
            new FormGroup({
              name: new FormControl(ingredient.name),
              amount: new FormControl(ingredient.amount),
            })
          );
        }
      }
    }
    this.BugForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(bugName),
      imagePath: new FormControl(bugImagePath),
      description: new FormControl(bugDescription),
      priority: new FormControl(bugPriority),
      status: new FormControl(bugStatus),
      ingredinets: BugIngredients,
    });
  }
}
```

### my error msg

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'ingredients'
    at _throwError (shared.ts:295)
    at setUpFormContainer (shared.ts:266)
    at FormGroupDirective._setUpFormContainer (form_group_directive.ts:322)
    at FormGroupDirective.addFormArray (form_group_directive.ts:227)
    at FormArrayName.ngOnInit (form_group_name.ts:170)
    at callHook (core.js:2573)
    at callHooks (core.js:2542)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2493)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:8449)
    at ɵɵadvance (core.js:8432)
```

i have tried outsourcing the controls method to ts file but keep getting the error pls help...

Comment: ingredinets ?..

Comment: As @MikeOne as pointed out, at the initialization of the `BugForm` variable, you have `ingredients` spelled incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I misspelled  ingredients  to  ingredinets guess I'm dyslexic